# onclick pass class of element to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

i wrote a code like this

```
<?php
$extCount = 0;
foreach($this->externalReferal as $externalReferal)
{
$extCount++;
?>

    <div class='fieldtestPct' >
      <div class='fieldItemLabel'>
                <label for=''><?php echo $externalReferal->getConsultantname(); ?> ( <?php echo $externalReferal->getSpeciality(); ?> )</label>
      </div>
        <div class='fieldItemValue'>
                <input type='checkbox' class='ext_ref_list<?php echo $extCount; ?>' name='ext_ref_cons[]' value="Consultant<?php echo $extCount ?>" >
         </div>
    </div>

<div class='fieldtestPct'>
      <div class='fieldItemLabel'>
                <label for=''>Current Visit</label>
      </div>
        <div class='fieldItemValue'>
                <input type='checkbox' class='current_visit<?php echo $extCount; ?>' name='current_visit[]' value="" onClick ='currentVisit(this.class)'>
         </div>
    </div>
<div class='fieldtestPct'>
      <div class='fieldItemLabel'>
                <label for=''>Full Data</label>
      </div>
        <div class='fieldItemValue'>
                <input type='checkbox' class='full_data<?php echo $extCount; ?>' name='full_data[]' value="" onClick='fullData(this)'>
         </div>
    </div>

                <div class='clear'></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here i need to do dynamic action on click of checkboxes. how do i pass the selected element class/data to javascipt .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this.className` instead of `this.class`.

> The name *className* is used for this property instead of *class* because of conflicts with the "class" keyword in many languages which are used to manipulate the DOM.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classname

Comment: and how do i pass the Id of the element